# Installation guide for Matex and Ghostscript on Mac system for compatibility with Mathematica

Tags: matex

I require assistance with installing and configuring Matex and Ghostscript for use with Mathematica on my Mac system. I have successfully installed Matex and executed the following codes on Mathematica notebook provided in [this](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MaTeXInstall/) link, resulting in expected outputs

```
<< MaTeX`

MaTeX[HoldForm@Integrate[Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}]]

MaTeX["\\sum_{k=1}^{\\infty} \\frac{1}{k^2} = \\frac{\\pi^2}{6}", 
 FontSize -> 24]
```

However, I am encountering difficulties installing Ghostscript on my system. I have attempted to run the following command in terminal -

```
gs -h
```

Output -

```
GPL Ghostscript 10.01.1 (2023-03-27)
Copyright (C) 2023 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
Usage: gs [switches] [file1.ps file2.ps ...]
Most frequently used switches: (you can use # in place of =)
...
```

But the Mathematica code utilizing Matex and Ghostscript is still not functioning. Can someone please assist me with the installation process of Ghostscript, preferably by providing step-by-step guidance? I am not well-versed in this matter. Thank you in advance for your help.

While I run the following command

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{MaTeX["\\color{red}\\Omega_\\text{y}", 
     FontSize -> 30], 
    None}, {MaTeX["f \\;/\\; \\text{k}", FontSize -> 30], None}}]
```

I am getting the following error message  -
"MaTeX::texerr: Error while running LaTeX.
! Undefined control sequence.
 \color
{red}\Omega *\text {y}
\MaTeX{\color{red}\Omega*\text{y}}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!"

The problem is coming from the part "\ \color{red}". If I remove this, there is no error.

Comment: Apparently, Ghostscript _is_ installed on your system... Please describe what exactly happens when you try to use _MaTeX_. E.g., are there any error messages? Honestly, "still not functioning" is a quite useless description of the problem. It makes it very hard for others to guess what the cause is and how it can be resolved.

Comment: I've included the error I'm getting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since this issue had nothing to do with Ghostscript, can you please edit the title (and preferably also the question contents) so future readers wouldn't be confused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you simply have to add the `xcolor` package to `MaTeX` preamle. Try

```
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{xcolor}"}]
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks for answering. If there is a problem with Ghostscript, then MaTeX will not work _at all_. The fact that some commands succeeded shows that Ghostscript is fine.

Comment: @henrik-schumacher
I am still getting the error. Kindly see here - https://imgur.com/a/oEzsLUk

Comment: Oops, `MaTeX` wants `"Preamble"` to be a list. (See my edit.)

Comment: @henrik-schumacher
Thank you very much.It is finally working. Your kind response is much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome!